# Display Crystal Reports in HTML without using ASP Crystal Reports Viewer

Tags: c#, angularjs, crystal-reports, asp.net-web-api

I have an Angular Front End, and C# Backend for my current project, both are separated into their own projects. My question is, is there a way to display a Crystal Report in the browser without using ASP Crystal Reports Viewer? I've searched for weeks and been unable to find anything. I'm not using MVC, mainly because I'm not too familiar with it and how to use Angular with MVC. Essentially I have just static HTML pages, and I use Angular to call back to the server and get my data, I know I can issue a call and "load" a crystal report, but then I can't figure out how I'd actually display it, since I don't have a crystal reports viewer at my disposal due to not using Web Forms. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Through .Net code (that you could expose through a web service) you can "export" into various formats (PDF, Word Doc, Excel, Text, HTML).  You could make a JavaScript call to a C# web service call that loads the reports and exports HTML then another call to Render that (or get it's results back from the original call, not sure how long your reports take to run).